# RRDtool if one value is skipped in update the next one is missing also

Tags: rrdtool

I have created RRD DB, which should receive update every hour and display values of received orders for last 24 hours:

```
rrdtool create db.rrd --step 3600 --start 1381230000 DS:measurment:GAUGE:4800:0:U     RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:24
```

Everything is working OK, except fact when I miss one value in update two of them are missing from database:

So let say i have:

```
....
1381240800:1203 
1381244400:1302 
1381248000:1132  
1381251600:988
....
```

But if the second update wouldn't be received (1381244400:1302), the third (1381248000:1132) will be missing dispite fact that it arrived.

Can someone tell me why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that if the previous update is missed, the interval between the last and the current update is larger than the 4800 seconds you specified in your `DS` definition. Therefore rrdtool will treat all data between the last and the current update as *UNKNOWN*.

In rrdtool 1.4.8 I have introduced a special case for `GAUGE` `DS` updates where the previous update is more than `MRHB` in the past. In this case rrdtool will now treat the data supplied as valid from `now-MRHB` until `now`.

Comment: So, as I understand, after issueing "rrdtool update db.rrd 1381240800:1203 1381248000:1132 1381251600:988" (I've omitted one interval) on my current db setup (from first post) this should be automatically taken care of or I must add some option to update command? Sorry I'm newbie and I've tried to find that info on your site but it seems that I'm unable to. I'm using 1.4.8

Comment: Would it help if i create DS with 2x step interval?

rrdtool create db.rrd --step 3600 --start 1381230000 DS:measurment:GAUGE:7200:0:U     RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:24

But then the missing value would be populated with next step value (if it comes)? Am I right?

Comment: well if you miss one update, there will still be a gap unless you increase the MRHB ... best is todo some experiments :-)

Comment: I did some experimenting, but I haven't had success in achieving what I want. :( So with first example (heartbeat = 1,5xSTEP) I understand why I'm getting 2 UNK values. When I put my heartbeat to 2xSTEP then if value is missing, that missing value is replaced with value of next update (if it comes). But how can I achieve that missing value is set to UNK without next value being UNK also OR missing value is being interpolated from next update(if it comes). Please help :( Sorry for bothering

Comment: I don't really know what you are after ... you may want to create some samples and update your question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Hi I face to the same issue with rrdtool-1.4.7.

My questions to Tobi Oetiker:
1, whether the following use-case is do-able with rrdtool or a wrong concept.
2, what exactly the behaviour changed in rrdtool 1.4.8

Usecase: with data set's like the case above a am about render a "bar chart". On each "step" I provide usually one PDP (an update). I also define a MAX consolidation function where xff is 0 or 0.1, and keeps all from every step to render a graph 1:1 using an AREA.

So basically for RRD where step is 1day:
DATE: 2014-10-10 VALUE1: 35
DATE: 2014-10-11 VALUE1: 27
DATE: unknown
DATE: 2014-10-12 VALUE1: 89

The requested output, is a bar chart with three columns, where third is missing.

Similarly as Neven I have played with HB of 1x, 1,5x, 2x of the STEP but no success - the next value (after an unknown) is affected. Generally all edge cases (starting, ending) has kind of affection. In the above case, I miss Monday and Friday values. This is no issue for frequent data sources, but the simple case like "barchart" per day pains.

Neven: My answ, is that we probably use wrong use-case. As RRDtool stores "rates" per time interval it always will do kind of "consolidation". An partial solution which is not allways possible is to update frequently and aggregate on RRD, like increasing a STEP=NNN spec. in graph definition.